# Objective-c,how to insert a font file into System/Library/Fonts by code?

Tags: iphone, fonts, insert

guys.
how can i insert a font file into System/Library/Fonts by using objective-c?
thanks

Comment: In iOS you can add a font to your project. Is that what you want? I don't think you can add a system-wide font.

Comment: yes. thanks.i use a uiwebview to open a pdf ,but the pdf use a font that is not installed by iphone...      can you tell a way to solove this problem,thanks.Do i need to write a pdf viewer by using quartz?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to modify the system files at runtime that's for sure. Now, you can embed your font into your project and use them and that's the way you do it.

read this : http://www.waterworld.com.hk/en/node/157